# Microsoft Access VBA - Permission Denied when running WScript.Shell.run

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

When running the below VBA in Access, Microsoft Box pops up indicating "Permission Denied"

```
Public Sub RunPolicyImportBatchFile()

    Dim strCommand As String
    Dim lngErrorCode As Long
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

    'Run the batch file using WshShell object
    strCommand = "C:\Support\Masters\Access\Policy\Batch\PolicyRename.bat"
    wsh.Run strCommand, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

This runs fine on my computer, but receive permission denied when running on a peers computer.

Comment: The path, pointing to a local drive (C:), must exist on all computers. The permissions also have to be set up correctly for the users to be able to access the files. Can the user run that .bat file manually?

Comment: He can run the batch files manually by clicking on them in File Explorer

Comment: I have tested your code. It works. This means the problem is environmental.